# Windows Vista: error 646 raised by Windows Update when applying update for Office 2007

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

I have 12 Vista desktops on a Windows 2003 SBS domain. The updates are controlled through Windows Update Services 3.

The desktops have the same hardware and software configuration: Windows Vista Business x86 and Office 2007 Small Business.

Applying Office 2007 update raises the 646 error on only 2 desktops. All the others work (all of them were installed in the same day and have been configured the same).

No solution found on google worked for me: I have tried reregistering the Windows Update dll's with regsvr32.exe, I have disabled the UAC.

I have found two solutions to work:
- downloading the standalone upgrade package, and running it from a domain user account which is an administrator for the desktop
- logging in as domain administrator and applying updates through Windows Update

I am trying to find out what I am missing so that the domain user can update it's desktop.

WindowsUpdate log:

2010-09-29  15:54:38:819    4456    14b0    Handler :::::::::::::

2010-09-29  15:54:38:819    4456    14b0    Handler :: START ::  Handler: MSI Install

2010-09-29  15:54:38:819    4456    14b0    Handler :::::::::

2010-09-29  15:54:38:819    4456    14b0    Handler   : Updates to install = 1

2010-09-29  15:54:38:819    4456    14b0    Handler Extracting MSP file stored in CAB usp10.cab

2010-09-29  15:54:38:850    4456    14b0    Handler MSP update {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.0 using full-file patch

2010-09-29  15:54:38:850    4456    14b0    Handler   : Batch installing 1 updates

2010-09-29  15:54:39:428    4456    14b0    Handler List of MSPs in transaction:

2010-09-29  15:54:39:428    4456    14b0    Handler   C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\e363ad62e026bc78d37476c364c74e4e\img\usp10.MSP

2010-09-29  15:54:39:428    4456    14b0    Handler MSP final command line: DISABLESRCPROMPT=1 LOCALCACHESRCRES=0 NOLOCALCACHEROLLBACK=1 REBOOT=REALLYSUPPRESS MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL=Disable

2010-09-29  15:54:43:826    1100    9a0 Report  REPORT EVENT: {90D40844-B61B-4DA8-889C-4DD82DA1E171}    2010-09-29 15:54:38:819+0300    1   182 101 {06B68063-79B6-40D8-8502-21BB6608AD23}  100 80070643    AutomaticUpdates    Failure Content Install Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070643: Actualizare pentru Filtrul de poştă electronică nedorită din Outlook 2007 (KB2291599).

2010-09-29  15:54:43:826    1100    9a0 Report  CWERReporter::HandleEvents - WER report upload completed with status 0x8

2010-09-29  15:54:43:826    1100    9a0 Report  WER Report sent: 7.4.7600.226 0x80070643 06B68063-79B6-40D8-8502-21BB6608AD23 Install 101 Managed

2010-09-29  15:54:43:826    1100    9a0 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    4456    14b0    Handler MSP Error List:

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    4456    14b0    Handler 1: 1606 2: 0X1.32B600P-1022PPDATA\

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    4456    14b0    Handler 1: 1606 2: 0X1.32B600P-1022PPDATA\

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    4456    14b0    Handler   : MSI transaction completed. MSI: 0x80070643, Handler: 0x8024200b, Source: No, Reboot: 0

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    4456    14b0    Handler   : WARNING: First failure for update {0980C258-E920-442E-81FB-CA2FCA507D87}, transaction error = 0x8024200b, MSI result = 0x80070643, MSI action = CostFinalize

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    4456    14b0    Handler   : WARNING: Operation failed at update 0, Exit code = 0x8024200B

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    4456    14b0    Handler :::::::::

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    4456    14b0    Handler ::  END  ::  Handler: MSI Install

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    4456    14b0    Handler :::::::::::::

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    1100    d14 AU  >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Installing update [UpdateId = {B67EA9A1-981A-4B30-A12A-B3617B3868E4}]

2010-09-29  15:55:07:295    1100    d14 AU    # WARNING: Install failed, error = 0x80070643 / 0x00000646

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve the update issue: on those 2 desktops, the initial user (the one created during Windows initial configuration) was deleted. I have reinstalled Windows on those 2 computers. This time I haven't deleted the initial user after connecting the desktops to the network through http://server/connectcomputer. Now the Office updates are applied without any issues.